# AWS anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource. Private API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have a REST API Lambda function deployed to a private subnet, where the API Gateway type is private. Following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/) I have set up a vpc endpoint to private API gateway to the two public subnets of the same vpc as the lambda functions private subnet. The corresponding security group of the vpce allows all traffic.

If I try to query the API endpoint from an EC2 instance in the public subnet, I get the following error:

```
 anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on the resource.
```

I cannot find the issue, as the resource policy of the private API gateway looks as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:xxxxxxx:xxxxxx/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-xxxxxxxx"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The template I used had `sourceVpc` instead of the `sourceVpce`, which was causing some issues.

Answer (score 1):

actually, what @peterhack said was the answer for me as well.
Used the provided template "VPC Whitelist" with all placeholders was the problem:

```
...xxx:/{{stageNameOrWildcard}}/{{httpVerbOrWildcard}}/{{resourcePathOrWildcard}}
```

replacing with `...xxx:*/*` fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed the docs you have provided docs to and what you have written. I believe I found the cause of your access problem.

As you mention that you created an EC2 instance in the public subnet. By default that subnet will have an internet gateway available so in fact your VPC endpoint won't be used to access the private API Gateway. In the docs they also say the following;

> To emphasize the “privateness” of this API, test it from a resource that only lives inside your VPC and has no direct network access to it, in the traditional networking sense.

Assuming your policy is correct, correct region is used in your resource block and your vpc endpoint id is correct, you simply require to spin up another ec2 instance inside private subnet. Then the following process should work;

1. ssh onto instance in public subnet
2. from public instance ssh into the instance in the private subnet
3. perform invoke action from that EC2 instance in private subnet

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was just trying what you mentioned. So I ssh onto my linux bastion which is in the public subnet, from where I ssh onto a instance which is in a private subnet. Still, the error remains. What should be noted: The lambda is deployed to a different private subnet as this is only for lambda functions due to a broader ip range for auto scalability.

Comment: Last two things I would check then are; 1. In VPC endpoint configuration subnets that all private subnets are ticketed, 2. Security goup used, allows for HTTPS access to the endpoint for the entire VPC IP address range.

Comment: I have tried a few things, here my current setup which is still not working: lambda function deployed to two private subnets, security group allows all incoming traffic. In one of the private subnets I have deployed an EC2 instance, from which I try to invoke the lambda function. The vpc endpoint is setup with the two private subnets and the security group allows all incoming https traffic. I am very confused... I cannot see what I am missing?

Comment: @MC_ Had the same problem as the OP, That made the trick. What I am trying to understand is, when i got into the api gateway console, it give me a link to access the API which is working. But when i try to use the VPCE dns, i get this: {"message":"Forbidden"}. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your security group on the api gateway endpoints?
You need to use

Ingress:
https source CIDR of your vpc.

Outgress:
all traffic, 0.0.0.0/0

I found that if you use sg- in the sg (Ingress), it won't work. After I change as CIDR, it works now. I can call this api from the basion machine.

Comment: What worked for me: arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:xxxxxxx:*/*

Comment: If you need, you can reference here: https://github.com/imyoungyang/myAWSStudyBlog#part3-private-links-for-aws